# A materialized view log is required what types materialized views

Tags: oracle11g

A materialized view log is required for all types of materialized views. True False. I am thinking it is false is that anyone who can explain me.
and also You can create b-tree indexes on MVs(materialized views)?
True False.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Materialized Views need log, only fast refresh materialized view need log.

Comment: can we create b-tree indexes on MVs(materialized views)? True False. what about this i am thinking this is true

Comment: you are correct , index can be created on materialized views.